# Difference in replacing a single bolt by linear bolts in Storm topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

In my Storm topology, I am having a big program logic kept in a single bolt. Now I divided big program logic into small bolts which are arranged linearly. Does it make any difference in its performance ?

Comment: It depends on the number of device you add. Did you check the performance ?

Comment: It can run faster, or it can run slower, depending on the granularity of the original and resulting bolts. The rule is, avoid bolts which do little work, execution time should be at least 1 millisecond.

Comment: this is a real "it depends" scenario. Perhaps you could flesh out your question with some more details about the task?

Comment: In my topology, I am creating a dictionary of words. I am having one spout and two bolts. Spout will read a paragraph of text and emits each line as a message to first bolt. First bolt will split each line into words and emit a message with two fields( word and its first character), Second bolt receives message from First bolt and according to starting character of the word store that word in corresponding database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description in your comment:

> In my topology, I am creating a dictionary of words. I am having one spout and two bolts. Spout will read a paragraph of text and emits each line as a message to first bolt. First bolt will split each line into words and emit a message with two fields (word and its first character), Second bolt receives message from first bolt and according to starting character of the word store that word in corresponding database

I would say that this is a good multi-bolt scenario. I've (attempted to) draw a naive topology below. The word splitter bolt reads a paragraph and emits the word/character pair to the counter bolts (grouped by word). The counters can handle persistence themselves, or alternatively hand off to another bolt (not drawn here) that does the persistence.

```
                       / B (counter) 
  / B (word splitter) / B (counter)
S ...                 ...
  \ B (word splitter) \ B (counter)
                       \ B (counter)
```

You might consider writing this in trident rather than using bolts, especially as the activities performed by the bolts (at least as described here) are quite simple.